# Isometric embedding from X to $\mathbb{R}^4$(TIFR GS 2017)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, isometry

Does there always exist an isometric embedding from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$ for finite $X$.

I think yes, because I think every finite space can be isometrically embedded to a Hilbert space. Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider a lower dimensional analog. Is this possible for $\Bbb R^2$? What if we have $4$ equidistant points?

Of course, we can embed these points in $\Bbb R^3$ as the vertices of a regular tetrahedron.

Comment: So then, is the answer yes, because I can think of a square in the plane to which a map can be done?

Comment: No, the answer is no. The opposite corners of a square don't have the right distance between them.

Comment: What about points equidistant on an n-sphere?

Comment: Try that in 2 dimensions, see how far that gets you. Remember to consider *every* pairwise distance between points.

Comment: True, its not possible, but as you showed for $\mathbb{R}^3$, is it possible for odd n?

Comment: @vidyarthi any $n+1$ mutually equidistant points (i.e., vertices of a regular $n$-simplex in $R^n$) cannot be embedded isometrically in a lower dimensional euclidean space.

Comment: It's not possible for $\Bbb R^3$. It **is** possible with 4 points (in which case the points would form a regular tetrahedron), but how would we add a 5th point in such a way that it has the correct distance to every other point?

Comment: @r9m But 4 points are embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ isn't it?

Comment: @vidyarthi 4 equidistant points, sure. But not 5.

Comment: @r9m we can embed three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So shouldn't it be $n+2$?